# Regex for substring match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have list of strings
`03000_textbox (57447)`,
`03990_textbox (57499)`,
`03000_textnewbox (57447)`

I want to use regex to capture 1st and 2nd elements of list.
Anything that contains substring `textbox` i.e.
`03000_textbox (57447)`
`03990_textbox (57499)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex you're looking for :

```
[0-9]+_textbox \([0-9]+\)
```

Live sample : https://regex101.com/r/2oiwcF/1
Don't forget to put a global (g) flag so you can get every match and loop into.